# Suppose X follows the N(0,$σ^2$) and Y|X=x follows N(ρx,$σ^2$). What is the Cov(X,Y) equal to?

Tags: probability

Given the distribution of $X$ and conditional distribution of $Y|X=x$ how do I find the covariance of $X$ and $Y$?
The pdf of $X$ as well as the pdf of $Y|X$ is known so to find the pdf of the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ I used the formula 
$$
\begin{split}
f(x,y)&=f(y|x)f(x)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right)^2}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(y-ρx)^2}{\sigma^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma^2 2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{y^2+ρ^2x^2+2ρxy+x^2}{\sigma^2}\right)}\\
\end{split}
$$
I am not sure how to proceed further to calculate $E$($x,y$) after this step i.e. how to proceed with the double integration of the above function multiplied by $xy$?

Comment: You shouldn't have changed a $y^2$ to $x^2$ there. You may wish to look up the multivariate Gaussian distribution's covariance matrix.

Comment: Sorry that's my mistake. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{E}(xy) = 4 \rho \sigma^5 \sqrt{2 \pi} \ $. As $\mathbb{E}(x) = 0 \Rightarrow cov(x, y) = \mathbb{E}(x y)$.

You just need to use the fact, that $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} x \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}(ax + b)^2} \ dx = - \frac{b \sqrt{2 \pi}}{a}$

Comment: I can't seem to reduce the pdf in the form $$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} x \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}(ax + b)^2} \ dx$$

Comment: Not a pdf, $E(xy) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} x \ dx \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} y \cdot p(x, y) \ dy$

Comment: The correct answer given is $cov(x,y)=ρσ^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$Cov(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$$
Use the law of total expectation to find $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$.